# Metallic bonds get weaker during electrostatic induction?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, atoms, metals

If the cations are held together by the sea of electrons (metallic bonding), and if we apply electrostatic induction then what happens to the region of atoms that have a deficit of electrons? Are their bonds weaker? How about the region with an excess of electrons - are their bonds stronger?

Either the above ideology is incorrect or actually the strength of the bonds have little to do with the sea of electrons? I briefly read somewhere that metallic bonds are more like covalent bonds, but delocalisation also occurs. This makes sense to me as the bond strength is uniform throughout the body, it's just the delocalised electrons that move.

Answer (score 0):

In a metal, the electrons of lower energy orbitals are bounded to its nuclei. But the higher energy orbitals are not localized that way. The atomic orbitals join as to speak to form bands, with a very small difference of energy and momentum between the available quantum states. The bands belong to the solid as a whole, and the electrons are free to move around.

When a charge is near a metal, the electron cloud loses its isotropy to cancel any electric field inside. The mettalic bond is not affected because the effect of the nearby charge replaces the role of the missing electrons in that region.

On the other hand, if the electrons didn't move (as in an insulator), the electrostatic interaction between nuclei and electrons in that region would change.

Comment: That's interesting... so the electron gaps caused by the charged body are replaced with the negative charge from the charged body? Kind of like 'phantom' electrons fill in the gaps?

Comment: The only thing I don't get about that is the electron's field vector is omnidirectional, which causes the bonding. But the vectors of the external charge is somewhat unidirectional from the perspective of the cations.